# common lisp - replace same values in list

Tags: lisp

I am quite new in lisp programing, so maybe this a stupid question, but anyway I have a list of numbers like ( 6000 6100 6200 6200 7200 etc.) and I want to find and replace the second same value ( to add 1200 to the second same value) so the result should be (6000 6100 6200 7400 7200). Can you help me with this? Thank you very much.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: - tried to construct some loop with one original list and one shifted list, than some mapcar with lambda to get a t/nil pattern, but - did not get to a working result.

Comment: Show us your code, and from there we may be able to point you in the right direction

Comment: The one with mapcar is like this - (defun nahrad (s s1) (mapcar (lambda (x) (equal x (cadr s1))) s) (if (equal (car s) T) collect (+ (car s) 1200) else collect (car s1))) . I rewrited the try with loop so - do not have it any more...

Comment: @user7980164: It would be great if you could put more effort into your question. The requirements are very vague. Maybe you should write them down. If you have code, edit it into the question and format it readably. Show us what it does and where the problems are.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see why the falk downvote the question, honestly. While it is not an interesting question, it is a clear one. For the pedants out there, let me generalize it in an attempt to make it more interesting. I am new to lisp, and I need to apply a function to a list. The output of the function depends not only on the current element but also on the preceding and/or subsequent elements, what is the best construct to use?

I think the easiest is to use `loop`:

```
(defun nahrad (list change)
  (loop for f = nil then s
        for s in list
        collect (if (eql f s) (+ change s) s)))

(defparameter *test* '(6000 6100 6200 6200 7200))

(nahrad *test* 1200)
```

Comment: This does not FIND the second same value. *finding* usually means a search operation,

Comment: Your code also does multiple changes. The question talks about `the second same value`, which is singular. It does not say `every`.

Comment: Your. code might also replace the third same value.

Comment: Lol, downvoted. @Rainer Joswig: I agree with your last two comments. But how often have you had all the aspects of your algorithm known before you you've started programming it?

Comment: before I would come up with the algorithm, I would start clearing up the requirements.

Comment: I've downvoted your post because you used the words 'falk' and 'pedant'. Where it is really about learning to provide a more precise description of the requirements. What you describe as 'clear' is simply vague.

Comment: I also don't like that you code sets F initially to NIL, which works in your example, since no number is EQL to NIL. Still it looks bad.

Comment: @Rainer Joswig I think the nil question is moot here. What should happen when we add to the nil? In some applications an error should be raised; in others nil should be returned (in which case the summation needs to be redefined). In either case the code will work correctly. By the way, I fully concur with you on downvoting my answer for having a less than neutral tone; I still think though that the original question is not that unclear.